# Titanium mobileweb font face not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, titanium

we are developing apps for android, ios and mobile web using Titanium. We want to change the font of the text and it is working fine on android, ios, mobile web on emulator. But if you open the file on a browser (ie firefox), the font is not working.

There is the code for changing font:

```
"TextField": {
    height : 40,
    color : "#000000",
    returnKeyType : Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    backgroundFocusedColor : "transparent",

    font: {
        fontSize : 16,
        fontFamily : "OpenSans-Regular"
    }
}
```

And when you check firebug, it shows something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "mobileweb\F ontsOpenSans-Regular";
    src: url("mobileweb\F ontsOpenSans-Regular.ttf,mobileweb\F ontsOpenSans-Regular.woff");
}
```

which obviously not gonna work since the font-family shows the address and not the font name. I searched over the web and see if they have solution and they cant find one.

Maybe this is a bug but I would like to know if you guys have workarounds on this.

Ill appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text value above or below the "font: {}" section.

```
    text: " text in here will show up in your code "
```

By the way, this helped me with my app too, the font just didn't want to change from the default values.
So thanks for the help!! :-)